# How to display/show sqlite3 database on the tkinter interface with label instead of entry?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I find a way to show my data but this way used "Entry".

How can I change it into label or text?

[image]

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('d:\\hw3.db')

import tkinter  as tk 
from tkinter import * 

my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("400x250") 

data=conn.execute('''SELECT * from ss LIMIT 0,10''');
i=0 # row value inside the loop 
for customer in data: 
    for j in range(len(customer)):
        e = Entry(my_w, width=10, fg='black') 
        e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
        e.insert(END, customer[j])
    i=i+1


my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Simply change `e = Entry(my_w, width=10, fg="black")` to `e = Label(my_w, text=customer[j], width=10, fg="black", bg="white", bd=1, relief="sunken", anchor="w")` and remove `e.insert(...)`.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)